# GoogleMaps API V3 displaying in IE but not working in FF

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I have written code to dynamically display multiple markers on google maps using relevant information(address,lat,long,description etc)taken from the database.The problem is the google map works very well in IE but not getting displayed in FF.

Heres the code for displaying the google map and markers

```
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #dvMap { height: 100%; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myApiKey&sensor=false" > 
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){                  
        var mapOptions={                 
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat,markers[0].lng),
            zoom:8,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP        
        };
        var infoWindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"),mapOptions);
        for(i=0;i<markers.length;i++){                
            var data=markers[i];
            var latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat,data.lng);
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:latlng,
                map:map,
                title:data.title             
            });
            (function(marker,data){
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(e){
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map,marker);
                });                
            })(marker,data);
        } 
    }        
</script>
```

Here's my aspx page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="dvMap" style="width:50%; height:50%;"></div>     
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle, demonstrating the problem?

Comment: any errors in the console in FF?

Comment: Sorry.i dont get you.What do you meant by jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ - create a demo here, which shows the problem you are having. Or provide us with a link to your actual webpage

Comment: @Circadian No error in the console.Infact i am getting the contents inside div when i checked with firebug.But unforturnately div is not showing.

Comment: can you provide a url where we can see the page?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by adding `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` at the end of your onload function

Also please notice that your inline styles `width:50%; height:50%` will overwrite the styles specified in your `<style>` at the top of the page.

From what I understand you are trying to create a fullscreen map, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes i am create trying to create a fullscreen map

Comment: I tried putting your code at the end of the onload function but its not working